# bash: kong: command not found-KONG API Gateway

Tags: bash, kong

I installed Kong gateway in CentOS 7.2. I have changed configuration details at `/etc/kong/kong.conf` to configure PosgreSQL database. Attching my `kong.conf` file. No Kong command is running from my CentOS machine. Error :

`bash: kong: command not found`

How can I proceed. When I tried re-installing Kong gateway:

```
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror Examining kong-0.10.3.el7.noarch.rpm: kong-0.10.3-1.noarch kong-0.10.3.el7.noarch.rpm: does not update installed package. Error: Nothing to do
```

Please note I changed configuration for Kong only to configure the datastore,all others are in commented format.

> Do I need to configure more details other than datastore used?
> or do there is some specific path at which i can try Kong commands?

Comment: is kong in your `$PATH`?

Comment: echo $path gives /usr/local/kong:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin

Comment: `which kong` gives `/usr/bin/which: no kong in (/usr/local/bin/kong:/etc/kong:/usr/local/kong:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin)`
and `echo $PATH `gives `/usr/local/bin/kong:/etc/kong:/usr/local/kong:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin`

Comment: i would suggest you locate the `kong` file and add its location in `$PATH`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i was trying with a wrong user on same machine,when i tried with user who installed kong solved the issue